# How to prevent gnome from auto-mounting a partition?

Tags: linux, partition, gnome

I have a partition on my Hard Drive that I want users to be able to mount, but it shouldn't be automatic, so I've put this in my /etc/fstab:

```
     /dev/sda5       /media/data    vfat    defaults,user,noauto    0   0
```

It works great for command line. The partition is mounted only when someone explicitly mounts it.

But whenever a user starts gnome, it automounts the partition, even though fstab says it is not suposed to be mounted automatically.

I know this is almost certainly a gnome setting, but I just couldn't find it in gconf-editor (it looks too much like the Windows register editor for me).

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: I did a quick search and found a lot of ways to do this on old versions of Ubuntu, but nothing that works currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a patch to get gnome to honor the noauto flag:

http://patches.ubuntu.com/by-release/extracted/ubuntu/g/gnome-volume-manager/2.17.0-2ubuntu2/02_honour_automount_enabled_hint.patch

From the surrounding thread, it looks like it's been ignoring it for a couple of versions now:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=989666

Comment: For the record: using gnome 2.26.1 in Debian Sid I didn't even need to apply the patch. All I had to do was uncomment the device that starts with "<match key="storage.hotpluggable" bool="false">" in /etc/hal/fdi/policy/preferences.fdi. Thank you very much for your help!